# How to check whether the Street view panaroma data is available or not for a particular Latitude and Longitude values

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2, google-street-view

Well, 
I m getting all nearby places via google places API. , I set markers to all my near by places. I am calling builten google `Street view panorama` via intent on click event of the infowindow like this.

```
String uri = "google.streetview:cbll=" + latitude + "," + longitude
            + "&cbp=1,99.56,,1,-5.27&mz=21";
    Intent streetView = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(streetView);
```

note: I am passing the Latitude and longitude values in my URI

its working just fine. but the problem is that some times panorama viewer shows a Toast "StreetView is not available here" if the data is not available.

**Question**

So my question is that how can I check before starting my panorama viewer that whether a location with certain Latitude and Longitude values has the street view data available or not?

*I m using google maps v2 for android*